# Posting image/video to MySpace using API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, myspace

I am Working in Asp.net 3.5 with c# 2008.I have done authentication part & I'm also able to get all image URLs or videos from my application. I'm also able to send messages to MySpace. Now I would like to post images & videos.

Please let me know how can I post images/videos from my application.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a link to the Documentation on using Media Items API.

http://wiki.developer.myspace.com/index.php?title=OpenSocial_0.9_MediaItems

It explains how to use it.

you need to Issue a POST request on following URL

```
http://api.myspace.com/1.0/mediaItems/{personId}/{selector}/@videos
```

if its [image](http://wiki.developer.myspace.com/index.php?title=OpenSocial_0.9_MediaItems#Updating_a_Photo_in_an_Album) then set content-type to image/{type} like `content-type="image/jpg"` for jpg
these formats are supported:  .jpg, .gif, .bmp, .tiff, .png.

similarly for videos use content type like `content-type=”video/mpeg”`
these formats are supported .avi,.mov,.mpg,.wmv.

For more details please consider checking out above link.

For details on what a POST request is or what is its structure check out this http://www.jmarshall.com/easy/http/